# Crear botón para abrir nueva ventana existente TKINTER

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ventana

Hola tengo un problema para realizar un programa y que abra otra ventana con un archivo que ya está creado en python con TKINTER...

Tengo realizada ya la ventana de stock de un software de indumentaria, lo que me falta es **crear una ventana que contenga el botón que abra este archivo**.

No sé si la mejor manera es creando un botón o desde el menubar añadir la opción de stock.

Este es el codigo de la ventana de stock que guarda en una base de datos los productos
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

```
import sqlite3    
class Product(tk.Toplevel):
    db_name = 'database.db'
    
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.wind = window #almacenada para empezar a usarla
        self.wind.title('Control de Stock')
        
        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text='Registre un nuevo producto')
        frame.grid(row=0,column =0, columnspan = 3, pady=20)
        
        Label(frame, text = 'Nombre: ').grid(row=1, column = 0)
        self.name = Entry(frame)
        self.name.focus()
        self.name.grid (row =1, column = 1)
        
        Label (frame, text ='Precio: ').grid(row=2, column=0)
        Entry(frame)
        self.price=Entry(frame)
        self.price.grid(row=2, column=1)
        
        ttk.Button(frame, text='Guardar Producto', command = self.add_product).grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky= W + E)
                 
        self.message = Label(text='', fg ='red')
        self.message.grid(row=3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)
                 
        self.tree= ttk.Treeview(height= 10, columns= 2)
        self.tree.grid(row= 4, column=0, columnspan= 2)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Nombre', anchor= CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#1', text = 'Precio', anchor= CENTER)
        
        ttk.Button(text='ELIMINAR', command=self.delete_product).grid(row=5,column=0,sticky = W + E)
        ttk.Button(text= 'EDITAR', command = self.edit_product).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky = W + E)
        
        self.get_products()
        
    def run_query(self,query, parameters=()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor=conn.cursor()
            result=cursor.execute(query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return result
        
    def get_products(self):
        records = self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tree.delete(element)
        #consultando datos
        query= 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY name DESC'
        db_rows = self.run_query(query)
        for row in db_rows:
            self.tree.insert('',0,text = row[1], values = row[2])
    def validation(self):
        return len(self.name.get()) != 0 and len(self.price.get()) != 0
     
    def add_product(self):
        if self.validation():
            query ='INSERT INTO product VALUES(NULL,?,?)'
            parameters = (self.name.get(), self.price.get())
            self.run_query(query,parameters)
            self.message['text']= 'El producto {} ha sido agregado'.format(self.name.get())
            self.name.delete(0, END)
            self.price.delete(0,END)
        else:
            self.message['text']= 'El nombre y el precio son requeridos'
        self.get_products()
        
    def delete_product(self):
        self.message['text']=''        
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Por favor selecciona un registro'
            return
        self.message['text']=''
        name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        query = 'DELETE FROM product WHERE name = ?'
        self.run_query(query,(name, ))
        self.message['text'] = 'El producto {} dha sido eliminado'.format(name)
        self.get_products()
    def edit_product(self):
        self.message['text']=''
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Por favor selecciona un registro'
            return
        name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        old_price=self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
        self.edit_wind = Toplevel()
        self.edit_wind.title = 'Editar producto'
        
        #old name
        Label(self.edit_wind, text= 'Nombre anterior: ').grid(row=0,column=1)
        Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable=StringVar(self.edit_wind, value= name),state ='readonly').grid(row= 0, column=2)
        
        #new name
        Label(self.edit_wind, text='Nuevo nombre').grid(row=1,column=1)
        new_name = Entry(self.edit_wind)
        new_name.grid(row=1,column=2)

        #old price
        Label(self.edit_wind, text= 'Precio anterior').grid(row=2, column = 1)
        Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable=StringVar(self.edit_wind,value= old_price), state='readonly').grid(row=2, column=2)

        #new
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Nuevo precio').grid(row=3, column=1)
        new_price=Entry(self.edit_wind)
        new_price.grid(row=3,column=2)

        Button(self.edit_wind,text= 'Actualizar', command= lambda: self.edit_records(new_name.get(),name ,new_price.get(),old_price)).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)
    
    def edit_records(self, new_name, name, new_price, old_price):
        query = 'UPDATE product SET name = ?, price = ? WHERE name = ? AND price = ?'
        parameters = (new_name, new_price, name, old_price)
        self.run_query(query,parameters)
        self.edit_wind.destroy()
        self.message['text']= ' {} ha sido actualizado'.format(name)
        self.get_products()
        
if __name__ =='__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = Product(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta... ¿Que es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder. Yo tengo la interfaz de control de stock (que es el codigo que puse ahi) y quiero crear otra ventana que tenga un boton que al presionarlo se abra la de stock (el codigo que pasé aca)

Comment: El botón debe tener como comando una función que cree una instancia u objeto de esa clase. No hay problema con que sea el mismo nombre, ya que las variables generadas al presionar el botón serán locales.

Comment: Perdón por la ignorancia pero se me complica con este tema... o sea yo creo una función de la clase producto y la agrego al commmand del botón? no entiendo el código que me compartiste donde iría

Comment: Bueno, puedes hacerlo de otra forma, si lo que quieres es simplemente abrir la ventana, puedes usar ```app = Product()``` luego de crear la clase

Answer (score 0):

El botón debe tener como comando una función que cree una instancia u objeto de esa clase. No hay problema con que sea el mismo nombre, ya que las variables generadas al presionar el botón serán locales.

```
def __init__():
    window = Product()
    return 0
```

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo código poco ayudan a quien pregunta, adjunta un poco de explicación sobre como y porque tu propuesta soluciona el problema de OP. ;)

Comment: Hay una discusión en los comentarios de la pregunta